# Add New Files to .gitignore on Multiple Branches

Tags: git

I created branch "local" from my master branch. While working in "local" branch, I decided I wanted to add all files inside the directory `content/images/` to `.gitignore`. So I updated `.gitignore` with the directory path and gave the command `git rm --cached -r content/images`. Then I committed the repo.

Now, I want to merge "local" into master, but when I try to checkout master, I get the message:

> The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by checkout:

and it gives a list of all the files inside the `content/images/` directory.

I kind of understand why Git is having issues, but I don't know what to do about it. How do I add these files to `.gitignore`, and sync up those preferences across my branches?

Comment: Does `master` have tracked files inside `content/images`?

Comment: @Carl Norum Yes, the files inside `content/images/` were tracked before I created "local" branch, so they started out being tracked in both branches.

Comment: Then I'm not sure you can do what you're trying to do - git is just trying to protect you from losing information.  If you `git rm` those files on `master`, you'll be fine.  You probably want to update `.gitignore` on that branch, too. Ignoring tracked files is sort of 'bad form', traditionally.

Comment: That's what I figured too, but it won't let me checkout one branch while the files are untracked in the other. So if I `git rm` on master, it won't let me checkout "local" so I can `git rm` there, too.

Comment: Oh I see.  Just delete them from the filesystem.  Since they're untracked, your `local` branch won't care, and that will let `master` write those files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This [related question & answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2029759/having-trouble-checking-out-master-in-git-after-removing-directory-from-reposito?rq=1) solves my problem.

I just need to use the "force" command (`git checkout -f master`) to forcefully checkout master, then run `git rm --cached -r content/images` on that branch as well.